# Formula for calculating magnetic vector potential in presence of displacement current density only

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, displacement-current

Suppose to have a volume $\tau$ where a displacement current density $\vec{j_S}$ is present. Can the magnetic vector potential be calculated using the following formula?

$$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \int \int_{\tau} \frac{\vec{j_s} \,\,d\tau}{r}$$

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to expect that such an equation should hold? did you derive it from something else? or did you just make it up?

Comment: Yes, that formula is correct.